# C#: How to handle accessing of a property of a computed public get/set accessor

Tags: c#, vector, get, set, accessor

Sorry for the long question! I've been trying my hand at using get/set accessors, but I've run into a problem.

To give an example, I have a Vector2D class which has private double x and y values and public accessors X and Y for those values. I also have a public Direction property (of a custom type Angle which itself has public double Degrees and Radians properties). This Direction property has a *get* accessor which returns a new Angle object based on the values of X and Y, and a *set* accessor which changes the X and Y values based on the new Angle value passed in.

So if you have a Vector2D called vector you can use vector.Direction = new Angle(0), which works fine. But naturally it's also possible to write vector.Direction.Degrees = 0. This doesn't cause errors but it also doesn't work as intended, since the x and y values of the vector aren't updated.

After thinking about it I understand *why* this happens. When you write vector.Direction.Degrees, it uses the *get* accessor in Vector2D, which returns a new Angle based on X and Y, and then it accesses the Degrees property and its *set* accessor on *that* object, not the *set* accessor for the Direction property on the original vector object. In other words, the *set* accessor on vector.Direction doesn't get used in that scenario at all, and so the x and y values aren't updated. And that makes sense I suppose.

It's clearly confusing that you can access vector.Direction.Degrees and attempt to set it to a different value yet this doesn't actually do anything. But I also see that this behaviour is intended. My question is, what is a good way to deal with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT - Here's the relevant part of my class definition:

**Vector2D class**

```
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public double X { get => x; set => x = value; }
    public double Y { get => y; set => y = value; }

    public Angle Direction
    {
        get
        {
            return new Angle(X, Y);
        }
        set
        {
            double previousMagnitude = Magnitude;

            X = Math.Cos(value.Radians) * previousMagnitude;
            Y = Math.Sin(value.Radians) * previousMagnitude;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try overloading the = operator to use set function.

Comment: Can you show your class definition in the question? It might be possible to modify it to make it work.

Comment: This question really needs code to illustrate what you are asking.

Comment: @SvSv No overloading of assignment in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The (most) right thing to do is to make the *Angle* immutable, so that its Degrees and Radians couldn't be changed after creation. You'll probably need static factory methods Angle.FromDegrees() and Angle.FromRadians() to, as both degrees and radians are double so you can't use .ctor overloads.

Failing that, you'll need to create Changed event on Angle,subscribe the Vector2D to this event, raise it every time Degrees or Radians are set. Also unsubscribe from it when Vector2D.Angle is re-assigned... which seems to be a huge overkill, esp. if Angle objects could be shared between Vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning a new Direction value every time you access it anyways, I suggest not having a public set in Direction.Degrees and Direction.Radians at all, like this:

```
public double Degrees
{
  get { /* return degrees */ }
  private set { /* set degrees, but only from somewhere in the struct, for example the constructor */ }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public Angle(double X, double Y)
{
  this.Degrees = /*do computation based on X and Y*/;
  this.Radians = /*do computation...*/
}
```

Gives an error due to property inaccessible because of protection level:

```
myVector2D.Direction.Degrees = x;
```

Works:

```
myVector2D.Direction = new Angle(x, y);
```

This way you can force your users to use the set of Vector2D.Direction rather than that of Angle.Degrees, so you can detect and react to any changes.

Sorry for any formatting errors, I'm on mobile.